# HTML / jQuery Replace a space with a br

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to replace the second `" "` with a `<br>` via jQuery.

I have it working with a menu item that has 2 words but I need it to break on the second space on some of the menu items.

So I need to have tab1 and tab 2 split at the second space only and tab3 and tab4 split at the first (only space)

I have set up a Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/EpntC/

Here is the HTML

```
<ul>
  <li id="tab1"><a href="#">Menu Item One</a></li>
  <li id="tab2"><a href="#" >Menu Item Two</a>
  <li id="tab3"><a href="#" >Menu ItemThree</a>
  <li id="tab4"><a href="#" >Menu ItemFour</a>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tabs = ["tab3","tab4"];
  $.each(tabs, function(index, value){
  var el = $("#"+value).children("a") 
  var html = el.html().split(" ");
  html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
  el.html(html);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tabs = ["tab1","tab2"];
  $.each(tabs, function(index, value){
  var el = $("#"+value).children("a") 
  var html = el.html().split(" ");
  html = html[1] + "<br>" + html.slice(2).join(" ");
  el.html(html);
  });
});
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/EpntC/1/

Comment: No not like that, you just added a width to the LI. I need to add a <br> where the second space is. This will need to be done through jQuery. Good thought though.

Comment: Ah okay.  I'm afraid I'd probably tackle that in PHP as my knowledge of JQuery is not established enough.  Good luck.

Comment: Itemthree. And itemFour. Have no spaces, , is that intentional???

Comment: @stackunderflow yes that was intentional i should have mentioned that in my initial post i have edited it now to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('li a').each(function( index ) {
        var aHtml = $(this).html();
        var pos = aHtml.lastIndexOf(' ');
        aHtml = aHtml.substring(0,pos) + '<br/>' + aHtml.substring(pos+1)
        $(this).html(aHtml);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rtT9t/

Answer (score 2):

You could split the labels on the space and wrap them in `<p>` tags to achieve the same effect as `<br />` (and IMHO, `<br />` should be used sparingly, and not in this case).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li a').each(function(){
        var words = $(this).text().split(' ');
        $(this).text('');
        for(word in words){
            var wrapper = $('<p />', {text: words[word]});
            $(this).append(wrapper);
        }
    });
});
```

#### Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6jeb/

If you're concerned with the spacing between the words, you can style this via css:

```
li a p {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't explain this at first (have made an edit) but i need tab1 and tab2 to add the <br> after the second space and tab3 and tab4 to be split at the first space.

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach that still feels a little hacky, but was fun to play with. I might find a way to make it more scalable at some point - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/EpntC/2/

```
$('li a').each(function() {
    var thisText = $(this).text();
    var arrText = thisText.split(" ");
    if(arrText.length == 3) {
        var breakAfter = $(arrText).slice(1);
        var breakAfter = breakAfter[0] + '<br />';
        var newText = arrText[0] + ' ' + breakAfter + arrText[2];

    } else if(arrText.length = 2) {
        var breakAfter = $(arrText).slice(0);
        var breakAfter = breakAfter[0] + '<br />';
        var newText = breakAfter + arrText[1];
    }
    $(this).html(newText);
});
```

Comment: Very interesting approach! But it isn't working 100% perfect for me yet, there are some complication to my real code then the basic example on the fiddle. I have a nav item that has no spaces and another one that has 3 space ughhh :) I am going to play around with what you have created as i think you have a much better approach than i do. But i am not very good with jQuery.

Comment: Uggggh indeed! :) Let me know if I can help!

Comment: If you can, share of your real markup. I think we can figure out a couple of things really quickly with the spaces.